# Could not find a declaration file for module. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am going through the Gatsby.js tutorial and in tutorial two, you have to import some fonts. When I try to import `theme lawton` I see this error under `import lawtonTheme from "typography-theme-lawton";`

I first did `npm install --save typography-theme-lawton`

```
  Could not find a declaration file for module 'typography-theme-lawton'. '/Users/react/tutorial-part-two/node_modules/typography-theme-lawton/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/typography-theme-lawton` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'typography-theme-lawton';`
```

This is my typography.js file:

```
import Typography from "typography";
//import bootstrapTheme from " typography-theme-bootstrap";
import lawtonTheme from "typography-theme-lawton";

const typography = new Typography(lawtonTheme);

//const typography = new Typography({ baseFontSize: "18px" });
//const typography = new Typography(bootstrapTheme);

export default typography;
```

This is my gatsby-config.js file:

```
  module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-typography`,
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `src/utils/typography.js`
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Also in the gatsby-config file, the word module is underline and this note shows:
`[ts] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module. [80001]`

I also tried `npm install @types/typography-theme-lawton` but it gave me errors

Answer (score 1):

Based on your  your problem，I guess you are using typescript, and the project can't find the ts module.
You need to install ts files.Try this:

```
npm install —-save @types/.....
```

Or, you can add a d.ts file in your project somewhere, and add the above in the file.

```
declare module typography-theme-lawton
```

#### [ts] File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module. [80001]

I assume you are using VSCode.Add this in the setting to enable it:

```
"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
```

PS: It's just a suggestion,so you can just ignore this.